# Using same table for similar objects in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, logic

This is mostly a desing/performance question.
Currently I am working in simple a project and I have tables that are practically the same, Example:

```
Table shirts
String Size 
String Color

Table pants
String Size 
String Color
```

In my program performance isn't a big priority since it does very basic tasks , but I got this question, in SQL,  Would it be more efficient to combine this tables and use a new column lets say category with some centinel value that is used to check if it is shirt or pants, like this:

```
Table clothing
String Size
String Color
String type
```

, or keep it in two tables making requests to both tables separetly ?

if this depends of the database type, I am using sqlite3 in case the answer would only apply to sqlite3.

Comment: your second solution is more engineered and it's base on object oriented design . and  for performance tuning you can use index for your table

Comment: There is no right answer. It depends. Normally I would be inclined to use one table. However, this may or may not scale. If at some time in the future, you need to add additional attributes to pants that aren't applicable to shirts this would have been a bad solution. On the other hand, it's very common to due this for stuff like return codes or basic name value pair lookup stuff.

Comment: Classic example of the object-relational impedance mismatch, if you want to read up on it. You can sort of represent inheritance in an rdbms, a clothing table and then a shirts/pants table that key to it, clothing having the common properties and shirts/pants being specific.. the last orm I worked with in any depth that implemented inherited objects on the client side did actually just use a single table and nulled out irrelevant properties.. No right answer, maybe consider an object db rather than a relational one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with all databases, SQLite stores the underlying data on "data pages".  These pages contain a certain number of records.  "Empty" records on the page occupy space.

If you have data that you spread among a bunch of tables, then you are likely to have many more partially filled data pages.  The consequence is a larger database to store the same records.  This in turn can result in somewhat slower queries.

This is one reason why you don't want to store identical data in multiple tables.  There are other reasons as well -- adding indexes is tricky, running queries on all the objects is cumbersome, maintaining the tables is more work.

However, in your example, t-shirts and pants are not exactly the same thing.  If your application is treating both as clothing, with exactly two attributes -- color and size -- then this is fine.  You can extend this with brand, fashion year, primary material, and other attributes that clothing might have.

But, if you need to start adding specific attributes, then you'll face a conundrum.  For instance, pants sizes are typically measured in waist and length.  T-Shirt sizes as S-M-L.  You are likely encoding these in a string -- and that might be fine for your purposes.

Because you have currently thought about your data model and you have compatible dimensions, I would be inclined to go with the second approach.  If you need to add bespoke features in the future, you still have multiple options:

- Add a `pants` table that uses the same primary key as the `clothing` table and add the additional features there.
- Create a new `clothingAttributes` table and use an EAV data model for additional attributes.
- Install a JSON extension to SQLite and use a JSON column for bespoke attributes.